# Is there an elegant way to check if a key and value exists in an object and then use it?

Tags: javascript

Working with redux and javascript in general, I find my self typing out verbose lines of code to use a single value in an object.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  valueIwant: state.data && state.data.user && state.data.user.valueIWant || ''
})
```

I know I could set a default state, but in many cases the `data` object could come from an API call or maybe I have tons of `data1`, `data2`, `data3` etc. that all comes from API's and It's not feasible to write default state for all of them.

Isn't there any shorthand way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is interesting. I'm sure I knew that somehow but forgot? Huh. (`5 && 'b'` gives `'b'` and not `true`)

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Yup. :-) I call `&&` and `||` [curiously powerful](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You don't actually call out `&&` the article. I knew about `||` but not `&&`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Well that's weird. In my head, most of the article was about `||` but then it mentioned `&&` near the end. I see no evidence of that when I use the link, though. Huh. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's weird but [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58755751/451969). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *will be*, and you can use it today if you're using Babel or similar (which you probably are if you're using React): [*Optional chaining*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  valueIwant: state.data?.user?.valueIWant || ''
//                      ^-----^------------------- ***
})
```

The `?.` means that if the value in front of it is `null` or `undefined`, the expression ends there and the result is `undefined`.

You could also throw the [nullish coalescing](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) operator at it:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  valueIwant: state.data?.user?.valueIWant ?? ''
})
```

That only uses the `''` at the end of what precedes is is `null` or `undefined` (not other falsy values like `0`, `''`, etc.).

Both proposals are Stage 3 and JavaScript engines are actively adding support for them. (Chrome's V8 engine has optional chaining currently, but behind a flag.)

Answer (score 0):

For now, the best way to do that is to use external modules like [dot-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-object).
Here's an example:

```
const dotObj = require('dot-object');
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  valueIwant: dotObj.pick('data.user.valueIWant', state) || ''
});
```

In the future, there will be a native way to refer to optional object properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding another lib, you could use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s [get](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) method:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  valueIwant: _.get(state, 'data.user.valueIWant', '')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this sometimes

```
val = (((this.state || {}).data || {}).user || {}).valueYouWant || defaultValue
```

If you've got an array in there you can do

```
val = ((this.state || {}).array || [])[index] || defaultValue
```

You can basically string that along as far as you want, as long as you're sure of the structure of the expected data.